# How to send const data to shaders?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I want to send `const int` variable from CPU side to shader so I could initialize the array in the shader conveniently.

But if sending with usual `glUniform1ui(programm, N)` shader compiler says that `N` must be const.

```
#version 450 core
uniform const int N;
int myArray[N];

void main() {
//...
}
```

Is this possible ? If yes what are the workarounds ?

***p.s.***
I know that this is not related to the definition of uniform variables which clarifies that uniforms are immutable per shaders executing

Comment: Uniforms are constant, but not compile-time constant (so not `const`​)[link](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Uniforms). You cannot initialize a static array like this. You should allocate a buffer of size N(texture or SSBO) from the CPU side and pass its length as the uniform N.

Comment: @ViNi89 hmm i think SSBO should be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constant is as the name says constant and cannot be changed from outside via one of the `glUniform` methods and is NOT a uniform.

If you want to change the constant value, you've to recompile the hole shader and changing the shaders text before.

### Sample ( Pseudocode )

```
GLchar** shaderSources = new GLChar*[3];
shaderSources[0] = "#version 450 core\n";
shaderSources[1] = "#define ARRAY_LENGTH 5\n";
shaderSources[2] = myShaderCode;
glShaderSource(shader, 2, shaderSources, LENGTH_OF_EACH(shaderSources, 2));
```

Shader:

```
int myArray[ARRAY_LENGTH];
void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) myArray[i] ....;
}
```

A different approach is using textures ( or [SSBO](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object) )  instead of arrays and get values of the texture without interpolation between the values.

Comment: but I dont change any const data here and what is NOT a uniform there ?

Comment: also I can't imagine what the placeholder is in glsl and how to replace it from CPU

Comment: @ampawd By definition a uniform cannot be a `const` like the one you need for you array. All array sizes must be predefined for the shader and you cannot change them after compilation. If you just put a define like `#define ARRAY_SIZE 10` in your shader it will compile and work, however if you need to define the size from outside you need to change it from outside or put it into `glShaderSource`.

Comment: ohh yeah, now I got what you mean. yeah it seems like recompiling shader with different N is one of approaches

Comment: why didn't you make the ARRAY_LENGTH in shader source as a variable not just string literal ?

Comment: i mean the placeholder

Comment: @ampawd A define has the advantage that it doesn not have to modify the original shader string. `ARRAY_LENGTH` is replaced by the compiler, all you have to do is to put 2 shader sources into the `glShaderSource` method. I recognized to late that i made a more complicated example than necessary, in my engine the most stuff runs automatic and i don't have to care about.

Comment: @FelixK.: Your pseudo-code will not have a `#version` declaration. Remember: that must *always* be the first (non-whitespace/comment) thing in a shader.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes true, thats what in my implementation comes always first. Fixed

Comment: @FelixK.: Then you have to make sure that there is no `#version` in the shader string. It's not specified what happens if you have two `#version` declarations.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well i consider that this is something you should be aware of when developing a engine, but of course you could check the shader before putting everything together. However this is not subject of the question right?

Comment: @FelixK.: "*However this is not subject of the question right?*" You gave a solution that, if he dropped his shaders into it with no changes, could yield a compile error. It is therefore important to at least point out in the answer that he needs to remove the `#version` declaration. So yeah, I'd call that the "subject of the question".